# Terraform attaching a load balancer listener to an Elastic Beanstalk load balancer. Not a valid load balancer ARN

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb, amazon-ebs

I am trying to attach a SSL certificate to Elastic Beanstalk load balancer that is created via terraform and attaches on spin up. The EBS Environment being spun up is going to be a web api, which is why I need to attach the https ssl certificate to the environment because I want to spin it up/down on command without having to manually attach it to the service every time.

What I have done is the code below, but I keep getting the error:

```
Error: error creating ELBv2 Listener (arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:profile:loadbalancer/name: ValidationError: 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:profile:loadbalancer/name' is not a valid load balancer ARN
status code: 400, request id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I originally tried:
  `load_balancer_arn = "${aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.ebs-env.load_balancers[0].arn}"`
but `aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.ebs-env.load_balancers[0]` returns the name so I couldn't just do .arn which led me to doing it by writing a custom string for the arn and having the name given from the EBS environments load balancer and appending that onto the ARN.

EBS creates a classic load balancer, and the ARN on AWSs website that I found is below, and the way I am formatting everything I quadruple checked and I am still get that error that it's not a valid ARN.

I've checked that the EBS name is the actual name of the load balancer in the AWS console and it is with the terraform made name on the spin up. So it is a valid name for the load balancer, but the error I keep getting described above still shows up even though I validated manually that the name is correct.
The AWS documentation led me to using:
`arn:partition:service:region:account-id:resource-id`
for the arn custom name, and finding that:
`arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:region:account-id:loadbalancer/name`
is the correct ARN for a load balancer which is what I am using.

Here is my terraform code that I am using to spin up/down this infrastructure:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "ebaTest" {
  name        = "EBA-test"
  description = "Development test EBS system"
}

resource  "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "ebs-env" {
  name = "ebs-env"
  application = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.ebaTest.name
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2 v2.2.10 running .NET Core" 
  cname_prefix = "ebsp-env"
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
    name = "IamInstanceProfile"
    value = "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
    name = "InstanceType"
    value = "t3a.micro"
  }
}
resource "aws_lb_listener" "cert-listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:aws-id:loadbalancer/${aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.ebs-env.load_balancers[0]}"
  port = "443"
  protocol = "HTTPS"
  certificate_arn = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:aws-id:certificate/cert-id"
  default_action {
    type = "fixed-response"
  }
}
```

If you have any other clarifying questions/confused about something I will reply as fast as I can.

Comment: Can you just tell me what you want to do? Create a listener or a cerficate for an LB created by Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: @MarkoE I am trying to create the listener and attach to an elastic beanstalk load balancer. 
The certificate is already created/validated before hand. 

It's to get around having to configure the DNS route every time/change the address to the api which can take hours to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aws_lb_listener` is part of AWS ELBv2, which is only for Application Load Balancers and Network Load Balancers. You stated you are creating a classic load balancer. I don't think you can update the certificate of a CLB through Terraform if Terraform itself is not managing the load balancer.

Is there any reason you are using a CLB instead of the newer ALB? Either way, [the correct method to do this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html) is by passing the ARN of the SSL certificate directly to the Elastic Beanstalk resource, as a setting:

```
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elb:listener:443"
    name = "SSLCertificateId"
    value = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:aws-id:certificate/cert-id"
  }
```

Comment: This was something I was trying to do earlier, but didn't get it fully at first. This does seem to work and open the port for a new listener, but it's not attaching the SSL certificate.

Comment: Well there's also `aws:elbv2:listener:default` : `SSLCertificateArns` but that's only available for ALB, not CLB. Honestly I think this is going to work much better if you upgrade to an ALB first. You might be able to use `aws:elb:loadbalancer` : `SSLCertificateId` but that is deprecated for some reason. At this point I suggest looking over the docs at that link I posted, that's all I'm doing.

Comment: Yeah, that seemed to work. It is deprecated which is not the best, but it does get the intended result. I am gonna mess around with that page! I originally tried to do the settings approach as well, but did not understand where I would find these results! thanks for your help in understanding terraform and this all as a whole!

Comment: I think CLB is technically deprecated to be honest, which is probably why that setting is deprecated. Again, I recommend upgrading to ALB.